# Let iOS Mail ask for confimation before loading large emails

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email

On MacOS, you still have that legacy option to set a size limit, above which a confirmation is needed to load an email. I can't find a similar feature on iOS Mail.

Background: Currently I'm spending my time mainly in an area with very poor edge cellular network (around 30 kbit/s). Usually, I can live with that, stuff like messengers and email and some syncing apps still work. But once someone sends an email with large pictures embedded, I'm stuck. Important text emails may wait behind that big monster, but I can't find a way to skip it to receive them.

And no: It's neither about images to be loaded from servers (I never load those) nor about large documents attached (Mail doesn't load those automatically), but embedded images.

How to stop them from being loaded automatically, preferably like with MacOS Mail?

Comment: Are you open to using 3rd party apps that can do this?

Comment: Preferably not, but I'd give them a chance, if Mail can't be configured that way (and that other app offers everything else I need). Feel free to give a recommendation as an answer.